# Cannot find the result of a Get method inside IOwinContext object

Tags: get, owin, middleware

I have an `OwinMiddleware` with an `Invoke` method looking kind of like this:

```
public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    ...
    //The next line launches the execution of the Get method of a controller
    await Next.Invoke(context);
    //Now context.Response should contain "myvalue" right?
    ...
}
```

The `Invoke` method invokes a `Get` method, located inside a controller, which looks kind of like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(some params...)
{
    ...
    return "myvalue";
    ...
}
```

After the execution of the `Get` method, the program goes back to the `Invoke` method of my middleware. I think that the response of the `Get` method, namely `myvalue`, should be contained inside `context.Response`, but I don't know where precisely, because it's full of things.

Comment: It would be in the body stream. This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to access the "myvalue" from inside the Invoke method to insert it into an arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy response is a stream and You need to do this to get response back in orignal form

```
 try{
      var stream = context.Response.Body;
      var buffer = new MemoryStream();
      context.Response.Body = buffer;
      await _next.Invoke(environment);
      buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      var reader = new StreamReader(buffer);
      // Here you will get you response body like this
      string responseBody = reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
      // Then you again need to set the position to 0 for other layers
      context.Response.Body.Position = 0;
      buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      await buffer.CopyToAsync(stream);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

Comment: This is accurate, you should update it to match the OPs use case and try to explain why you did what you proposed.

Comment: Yes the string responseBody is exactly what I was looking for.